# Permissions for html subfolders

Tags: php, html, permissions, directory

I have a basic website set up and within my html folder I have folders for ico, img, css and js. The thing is when a user browses to say mydomain.com/img they see a directory list of all my images. This doesnt seem right to me, is it a permission setting that I'm missing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

- Just insert a blank index.html file in the directory! This will prevent people from seeing the directory content listed.

**Solution 2**

- Just CHMOD to 0755! Will give a 403 forbidden error. This can be done trough a simple FTP program like FileZilla, but also from command line using this:

You can define for whom the permissions you are setting apply with these:

```
'u' = user
'g' = group
'o' = other
```

You can add or remove permissions using these:

```
'+' will add permissions
'-' will remove permissions
```

You can set these permissions:

```
'r' = read
'w' = write
'x' = execute
```

Usage:

```
chmod -R permissions /path/to/dir/or/file
```

Comment: I chmod'd to 0644 but that made the css inaccessible to my website. Again, is that something I'm missing? I think i'll go with the index.html page in the folder anyway.

Comment: My mistake, try chmodding to 755. This will cause the same forbinnen error! Also edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is easier that you thought. Just create some simple index.html page that either says that there is nothing to do or redirect you to the home page (than it should be index.php).